# Getting the word out - photography blogs and press

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

The best way to get new users to our site is through word of mouth. Therefore, if we can reach people who have big mouths (i.e., wide readership :), more people will know who we are and why we're awesome.

I'd like to compile a list of bloggers and journalists that you all think would be good to expose to this site. Bloggers include photographers who blog and people who blog about photography.

Note: This list is not a "who can I spam with press releases?" type list. Ideally, these people would explore the site, use it a little, and if they like us, do some sort of review / publicity. I encourage each of you to promote the site whenever you can, to whomever you can - I will not provide a form letter because we at Stack Exchange believe in honest-to-goodness one-on-one interaction. :)

Although someone posted a [great form letter over on Cooking.SE](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196/get-the-word-out-food-blogs-and-press) a long time ago...

There are already a bunch that I've heard suggested in chat, know from my own internetting, or have already reached out to, but it would be great to have them all in one place that can be curated collectively and continually.

I made my first answer community wiki, so if you have 100+ rep, please just add your contributions there.

Answer (score 1):

Bloggers:

- [Chase Jarvis](http://blog.chasejarvis.com/blog/)
- [David Hobby](http://strobist.blogspot.com/) (Strobist)

Other Sites:

- [nikonrumors.com](http://nikonrumors.com)
- [digital-photography-school.com](http://digital-photography-school.com)

Answer (score 1):

Bryan Carnathan from [The Digital Picture](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/).

Answer (score 1):

How about [Photojojo](http://content.photojojo.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

No one has yet mentioned [The Online Photographer](http://theonlinephotographer.typepad.com/the_online_photographer/blog_index.html). I'm surprised, because

1. it gets mentioned here a lot, and not just by me
2. the readership is pretty much exactly our target demographic
3. it's a popular site among enthusiast photographers

Comment: Cool, I will look into this. Thanks!